# converting Hibernate xml configuration file from hypersql to mssql

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-mvc, hypersql

My application is working fine withe hypersql in memory database however, When I have tried to move to MSSQL the application is throwing exceptions.

I have added dependency of the mssql in POM file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The following NOT-WORKING code for mssql in hibernate xml file:

```
 <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class,hbm</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">ABCD</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">0000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=c1;</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The following WORKING code for hypersql in hibernate xml file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class,hbm</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:howtodoinjava</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">150</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Application throws the exceptions like:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

CAUSED BY:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

 org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]

  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection setting is linked to the incorrect driver.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
```

Point it to the same one you imported in your pom.xml (`<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>`)

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```